# How to disable Magento 2 reviews

Tags: magento2, module, admin, review

I'm trying to disable the Magento 2 product reviews feature.
I tried Disabling the Module at the Magento 2 admin Stores\Advanced\Advanced\Magento_Review but the reviews tab on each product is still there.
Is there any way to disable it?
I know for sure that we could disable it in Magento 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command line option instead:

```
php bin/magento module:disable --clear-static-content Magento_Review
```

If you want to flush the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

(Run it from root of your Magento 2 dir)

Comment: Now it's not possible in M2.2. It has too many dependencies.

Comment: Cannot disable Magento_Review because modules depend on many modules core.

Comment: This is not possible as Review module have alot of dependencies in M2.

Answer (score 57):

Disabling the module on command line resolves in errors on different places. A better idea is to hide it with XML. Just create a child theme (if you don't have one already) like this:

[How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-magento-2)

and then inside your child theme create:

app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

and add this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.review.form" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Remember that all reviews are in review page in customer tab (disable too). Work great in 2.1.7. Work the same when added only on product page layout.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: to expand on @Patryk Padus post :
<!-- Remove My Product Reviews-->
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>

in Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

Comment: This should be the correct answer. We should never disable the module Magento_Review. so many other modules depend on it.

Comment: It,s not working Magento 2.2.2

Comment: Works well in Magento 2.2.3 with custom theme. Thanks!

Comment: works in magento 2.2.6. thanks

Comment: Works well in magento 2.3.1

Comment: Worked a treat on 2.2.6  - thank you

Answer (score 27):

In Magento 2.0.2 you will get an error if you try what @MagePsycho suggested. You still can disable the module output by changing its status in the Advanced-Settings of Magento 2.

Shops > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced and search for "Review".

You might wanna flush the cache afterwards.

Comment: This is the way to go. Reviews module is marked as a dependency by other core modules (such as Customer) and cannot be disabled.

Comment: from magento 2.2 section Shops > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced is removed, take Mike's answer as accepted.

Comment: But there is no advanced tab in Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 18):

In Magento 2.3 Commerce at least, you can disable Reviews in admin at Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Product Reviews
[image]

Comment: It works also for open source version

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works for both for Commerce and Open Source. No need to remove with XML or disabling the module from CLI.

Answer (score 8):

**In Magento 2.1** , disabling the ouput as @Max suggested, will cause a troublesome popin in the product view edit.

[image]

Not very cool.
It is caused by an Ajax Request, that finish in 503. And you will notice that there is sill a "Product Reviews" tab.
It worked on 2.0 because the admin was still rendered trhough blocks. Now, it's done with UiComponent.

The "Product Review Tab" is added trough the `adminhtml/di.xml` of *Magento_Review*

```
  <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="review" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Review\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Review</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

There is no way - or at least did not find how - to remove an argument. So we have to rewrite it, one way or another.

First i thought of doing a plugin on `Magento\Review\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Review`. But digging through core code make me discover a `Dummy.php` class. So in a custom module, create a `adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="review" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Dummy</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

And don't forget to add `<sequence><Magento_Review/>` in your `module.xml`. Because XML are merged in a precise order. It has to be AFTER *Magento_Review*

**And please note:** Disabling Ouput is **NOT** disabling the Module, as the title of this thread is mentionning. It will only hide it:

1. controllers will still be active. If you do a post on the proper action, the controller will still work, and you will even have a "success" message on the frontend.
2. you will still find menus in admin, in "Report"
3. every model logic, injection, observers will still apply.

Anyway, from my point of view, it still the best solution. Because forcing the disable of the module with `module:disable -f` seems a bit harsh...

Comment: Very interesting - seems like the Magento Devs need to flat out more things. Very good catch!

Answer (score 8):

create:

app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      ...
      ...
         <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
         <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true" />
         <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info1" remove="true" />
         <referenceBlock name="review_customer_list" remove="true" />
         <referenceBlock name="customers_review" remove="true" />
         <referenceBlock name="product.review.form" remove="true" />
         <referenceBlock name="review_view" remove="true" />
         <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data" remove="true" />

      ...
      ...
 </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you, this can also be used in a single product under Layout Update XML to remove reviews for a specific item.

Comment: It appears at least a link to the then non-existing review form still appears on the product pages. It can be hidden with CSS by hiding `.product-reviews-summary`, but perhaps there’s another rule that can be added to `default.xml` to actually remove it?

Answer (score 5):

In Magento 2.2, you should just disable it in app/etc/config.php

```
'Magento_Review' => 0,
```

Comment: Doing this does not check for module dependencies and may result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes, It's working in Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 3):

`php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Review` to disable a module on which other modules rely on. It has to be done first in test environment so that any break in functionality is noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Shops > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced and search for "Review"

or else

app/etc/config.php
'Magento_Review' => 0,

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.2.5 at least, simply [disabling module output](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html) through `app/etc/config.php` seems to work wonders:

```
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'advanced' => [
            'modules_disable_output' => [
                'Magento_Review' => '1',
                'Magento_Newsletter' => '1',
            ],
        ],
        // … other config
    ],
],
```

This removes related module output (forms, messages) from store fronts as well as the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up that in Magento 2.3.0 the situation is improved (as in no errors are shown on the frontend when not installing module-review), however DI compilation still fails as `Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid` is being referenced in `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\1Reviews`.

Your best best is still to disable module output or disable the module completely (but still have the code autoloaded).