# How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

I want to modify certain aspects of the out-of-the-box Luma theme but I would like to do it by preserving the original file(s) and also ensuring that whenever I update Magento I preserve my changes as well.

I want to do this by way of a Child Theme.

Does Magento 2 support child themes and, if so, how do I structure my directory path to make this happen?

Comment: I am grateful that you asked this question.  I was wondering the same thing!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Lets us create a child theme so our all custom themes in Magento 2 goes here:

> app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name

Let us assume, our company name is mycompany and our theme name is basic. We need to create following directory structure for our theme:

```
app
└────design
     └──────frontend
            └──mycompany
               └───basic
                   └──etc
                   └──Magento_Theme
                   │       └─layout
                   │             default.xml
                   └──media
                   │       preview.png
                   └──web
                   │  └─css
                   │  └─fonts
                   │  └─images
                   │  └─js
                   │ theme.xml
                   │ registration.php
```

**mycompany :-**

The name of the theme package

**basic :-**
The name of the theme. We can have multiple named themes inside the mycompany folder.

**etc/view.xml :-**

This file is used to specify product image dimensions, thumbnails etc.

**Magento_Theme :-**
This directory is used to override existing Magento’s theme files.

**Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml :-**
By default Magento2 assumes that your theme’s logo file should be: `/web/media/logo.svg`
If you want some other file for logo, then you must declare it in `default.xml` file.

This file is also used to override default theme’s settings.

**media/preview.png :-**
The preview of current theme.

**web :-**
This directory contains all the theme’s static data like images, styles, javascript, fonts etc.

**registration.php :-**
This file is required to register our theme to Magento2 system.

**theme.xml :-**
This is a compulsory file that defines our theme name, its parent and optionally theme’s preview image.

**Creating theme files**

Let us now create our files one by one.

> theme.xml ( app/design/frontend/mycompany/basic/theme.xml )

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Basic</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
   <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme -->
   <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- theme's preview image -->
   </media>
</theme>
```

> registration.php ( app/design/frontend/mycompany/basic/registration.php )

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/mycompany/basic',
    __DIR__
);
```

> default.xml ( app/design/frontend/mycompany/basic/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml )

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
           <arguments>
              <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/my_logo.png</argument>
              <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
              <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
           </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

At this point, our theme is ready. Clear your cache and we will now select our new theme from admin.

Now, login to admin and move to following path:

```
Content -> Design -> Themes
```

You should see your theme listed.

Now go to:

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Design
```

Choose Main Website in front of Store View at top left. Now click

```
Desgin -> Design Theme
```

Uncheck Use Default checkbox and pick your theme. Click Save Config, clear your cache and your new theme is ready. Check your home page.

[For more detail see here.](http://ashutoshpandey.in/blog/creating-a-theme-in-magento-2/)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive step-by-step guide @Arunendra. I will give it a try shortly and post back.

Comment: This is excellent @Arunendra. Worked perfectly. Just need to follow it completely without skipping any steps.

Comment: Great step-by-step @Arunendra. Just in case anyone runs into the same problems as me, the location where you apply your registered theme has changed from `Design -> Design Theme` to `Content/Design/Configuration`.

Comment: **Important note:** File `media/preview.png` must exist otherwise Magento will throw an exception.

Answer (score 6):

**Create directories:**

Go to root to the root directory and navigate to **app/design/frontend**, create directory **Demo**.

Now create **Mytheme** directory in **app/design/frontend/Demo.**

Create **Mangento_Theme** directory in **app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme.**

Create **layout** directory in **app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme/Magento_Theme.**

Create **media** directory in **app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme.**

Create **web** directory in **app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme.**

Create **images** directory in **app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme/web.**

**Declaration of Theme**

Create theme.xml file in app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme, and paste the following code in it:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Mytheme</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
<preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
</theme>
```

**Registration of Theme**

Now create registration.php file in app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme and paste the following code in it:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Demo/Mytheme', __DIR__
);
```

**Upload Theme Preview Image**

Go to app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme/media and upload your preview image (preview.jpg) here.

**Declaration of Theme Logo**

Go to app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout and create a default.xml file. Paste the following code in it:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="logo">
<arguments>
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mytheme-logo.png</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Upload Theme Logo**

Go to app/design/frontend/Demo/Mytheme/web/images and upload your logo (mytheme-logo.png) here.

**Apply Your Theme**

- Open the Admin panel of your Magento 2 and go to Content →
  Configuration.
- Click on Edit option.
- Select Mytheme from the Applied Theme drop down menu and click on
  Save Configuration.

**Run Commands**

Open SSH terminal and go to the root directory of your Magento 2. Now run all these commands one by one:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension to help you create a child easily from admin here https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-create-child-theme