# Review tab declaration in product page - magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, product, theme

I need to Remove Review tab and their content in product detail page. I can find Details and More Information tab in `catalog_product_view.xml` under the group attribute `detailed_info`. But I can't found anything related to Review tab Declaration.In debug mode also not provide that much detail to find layout.

for example I found Detail tab in `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
```

**which layout xml file contain review tab declaration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento have `Review` module. Check following file where declare `reviews.tab`.

```
Magento/Review/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Comment: OMG I thought all the product detail page elements are resides on Magento/Catalog. How you found  appropriate layout easily any tricks you have please share with this answer its more helpful to beginners

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the default luma theme, then go to

```
your magento root/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

add below line inside the `<body>` tag :

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
  <referenceBlock name="product.review.form" remove="true" />
  <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
```

If you are using a custom theme, you need to do the same change at below location :

```
your magento root/app/design/frontend/Your Theme NAME_SPACE/theme name/etc/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

**P.S.** Flush the cache after you finish, to see the change.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think my title lead to misunderstood the question, I need to know which layout contain reviews tab declaration(which xml file?).

Comment: upvote you for the effort, its useful :-)

Comment: Thanks, The first line of your question was misleading.!

Comment: For the custom theme case I believe you have an extra "etc" on the path. It should be `your magento root/app/design/frontend/Your Theme NAME_SPACE/theme name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Answer (score 1):

In magento2 you can remove any block by their name.
**For exp:** 
`<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>`

To do this we need to create a custom theme, don't touch the default Magento file for best practice.
For create a theme follow this link : [How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108699/21339), If you have already a custom theme skip this one.

Now open  **app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml** and under `<body>` node put the following code:

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
```

Clear your magento cache refresh the page.
In the same way you can remove other unnecessary  block from your site.

Comment: thanks for the reply I know this procedure already. I think my title lead to misunderstood the question, I need to know which layout contain reviews tab declaration(which xml file?).