# Correct procedure for making edits of 'pages.xml'

Tags: magento2

Apologies if this is kinda vague. I am attempting to edit a [theme](http://newsmartwave.net/magento2/porto/demo3_en) I have purchased, and I am having trouble making the changes appear on my site. I have created a child theme and would like to override some CSS attached to the header. When inspecting the `header` element I find there is some CSS attached:

```
.cms-index-index .page-header.type3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

When searching my the theme for this CSS, I found it twice, once in `magento2\app\code\Smartwave\Porto\etc\import\pages.xml` and again in the file `magento2\app\design\frontend\Magento\Porto Theme\app\code\Smartwave\Porto\etc\import\pages.xml`.

My assumption is that I need to create a copy of one of these files in my new child theme to override it.

My question is, which of these files should I be duplicating, and after making those edits, what would be the correct procedure for making the edits appear on my site?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't Edit anything directly in your theme because whenever you updated your theme with latest version you will lose all your work.Therefore I will suggest you to create a child theme of your current theme.
Here is a good tutorial for it. [I suggest you please read it.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108699/21339)

Comment: Is this tutorial assuming I am using the Magento theme as a parent, or it will work with any parent theme?

Comment: Yes it will work with any parent theme

Comment: Alright, sweet. I have done this, seems to be working. Will edit question to suit.

Comment: If it's help you, then don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: I mean, it was a helpful tutorial, but it doesn't exactly answer the question. Thanks a lot, though. I do appreciate the help.