# app/design/frontend/magento folder is emtpy - how do I edit my theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, css, frontend, design

I am new to Magento. I just installed Magento 2 on a MAMP local server. Everything works so far i figured out how to create all needed files in order to create my own theme. I activated it inside the backend and now I want to start to code my theme. It inherits the luma theme. After hours of reading tutorials and guides I am completely stuck. Where do I start? Let's say I want to change the background color of the header. I should be able to do this by copying and changing the parent themes content. So I copied everything inside the `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma` folder and put it into my custom theme folder which is `app/design/frontend/Mypackage/mytheme` Now when I activate my theme in Magento the site loads without any styling. What am I doing wrong? I am getting really frustrated and any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer here for create a theme in magento http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108699/21339

Answer (score 0):

Choose your Theme:

```
    Stores -> Configuration -> Design
```

After Choose your **custom theme** in back end:

Remove **pub/static** content

```
   rm -rf pub/static
```

then Regenerate the static file:

```
  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

remove var/* content

```
  rm -rf var/*
```

Then Check it.