# Magento 2 Simplest way to create a theme based on Blank with custom frontpage and nav

Tags: magento2

I am not very experienced in Magento 2 and I need to put together a demo which contain's a homepage custom structure and css too.

Basically I'm going to use the Blank theme but I need to change the Homepage where the Nav, page content and colors will be changed and the Nav will be moved in position. So I need to change Colors and Structure or the homepage.

What is the fastest's, simplest way to do this on Magento 2, even if it's a dirty way to do it (as it's only for a demo) ?

Comment: See my answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108699/21339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Magento is providing structure Layout like , empty, 1 column, 2 column-left, 2 column-right, 3 columns. Sometime when we implement the design we need to create new structure layout and set the design as per our theme.

**How to create custom structure layout**

1) We need to create layout.xml on the app/code/your-module/Customtheme/view/frontend

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
<layout id="homepage">
<label translate="true">Home Page</label>
</layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Now check this layout, It will display in cms >> Design tab, Catalog >> Design tab, Categories >> Design tab.

Form the above page we can choose the layout.

Then create homepage.xml which are define as a layout id in the path app/code/your-module/Customtheme/view/frontend/page_layouts. In the File we can define the structure of the page.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="empty"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
<container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
<container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
</referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Now Clear the cache from admin side and check the home page design.

you can chk http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/quick-tour-design-your-magento-2-0-homepage-layout/ for reference. It also might help you.