# Show brand attribute in product listing

Tags: magento2, attributes, catalog, custom-attributes

I would like to show the Brand attribute under the product name on the listing page. Attached is a screenshot for reference. [image: Reference]

Comment: What is  your attribute code and type of attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to override the template file to a subtheme.

Info on how to do that here: [How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-magento-2)

Then you can change the text, by replacing it with

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?>
```

Don't forget to set "used in product listing" to yes in the backend

Answer (score 0):

1) First to display your attribute as you want in listing products, check first this config `admin, Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`. select your attribute `brand` then check if `Used in Product Listing` is set to 'yes' if no, change it to 'Yes' then save.

2) You need to reindexall

3) Go to `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`under this class `class="product-name"` you add this one for the attribute `<h4><?php echo $_product->getBrand(); ?></h4>`.

4) Clear your cache and you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. First to display your attribute as you want in listing products, check first this config admin, Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes. select your attribute brand then check if Used in Product Listing is set to 'yes' if no, change it to 'Yes' then save.
2. You need to reindexall
3. Go to app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtmlunder this class class="product-name" you add this one for the attribute getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?>.
4. Clear your cache and you get what you need.