# Magento 2: How to display brand name above product name

Tags: magento2

I want display brand name above product name on product list something like that:
[image]

Additionally, it needs an additional inscription before the sale price text: "Retail price":
[image]

can anyone help me which files should I edit?

I have found in
app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                    <h5 class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getBrand(), 'brand') ?>
                        </a>
                    </h5>

                    <?php if(!$themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/review')): ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType,true); ?>
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                    <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
                    <?php if ($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_add_to_cart') == 0 && $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_hover_effect') == 1): ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <div>
                                <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add', ['uenc'=>$postParams['data']['uenc'], 'product'=>$postParams['data']['product']]); ?>" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['uenc']; ?>">
                                    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
                                    <button class="action tocart btn-cart hover_effect" type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                        <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </div>
```

and add this line but after replace file still no work. Can you confirm  that I put it in the right place?

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187401/show-brand-attribute-in-product-listing/187405#187405

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the **phtml** for this listing.
At that's case, you can help you can help of [Template Path Hints](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-magento-2.html)

Then add this above the product name

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getBrand(), 'brand') ?>
```

Also.you need enables for brand attribute for product listing from Admin >Stores > Attributes > Product> Find your brand attribute .
Then Used in Product Listing” options under storefront Properties are set to Yes.
This blog also help on this https://rafaelstz.github.io/magento/magento2-display-custom-attribute-catalog-list-products.html

Comment: I have update my topic.