# How to override admin footer.phtml file?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, overrides, footer

How to override admin `footer.phtml` file?

path: `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/footer.phtml`

Comment: did you created your custom backend theme ?

Comment: No, i didn't created

Comment: you need to create custom backend theme as link shared by @bhavin

Comment: i have created admin theme, how to override footer.phtml file

Answer (score 1):

To override file of admin theme, You can create your own admin theme by making parent theme as a magento default admin theme (Magento/backend).

Follow below tutorial for create your own admin theme.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html

Answer (score 1):

As you have created Magento Backend Theme.

Copy the below File from Magento Vendor Directory:

```
vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/footer.phtml
```

Create equivalent directory structure in your custom backend theme and paste the footer template file:

```
app/design/adminhtml/VENDOR_DIR/THEME_NAME/Magento_Backend/templates/page/footer.phtml
```

Comment: copied to app/design/adminhtml/Admin/backend/Magento_Backend/templates/page/footer.phtml but not working

Comment: I checked its working for me. Can you please double check backend theme is wokring

Answer (score 0):

Yes as mentioned you need to make a child theme of your current theme.  Basically it uses all the files of your current admin theme (extends) until you add in an override file into your child theme (footer.phtml).

If you search around there are some zip files containing a full child theme ready for you to customize.

See the following answers:

[How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-magento-2)

https://community.magento.com/t5/Theming-Layout-Design-Questions/How-to-create-a-Child-Theme-in-Magento-2/td-p/33253