# Magento 2.2.2 : set different design for multi website?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, design-theme

Is it possible to set design according to a website? I have two websites have a single store and single store view and want to apply color scheme combination differently according to a website.

As we did in M1 we just need to set skin path according to a website. How can I do in Magento 2.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate theme based on website. Then change CSS in individual theme that is set per website. You can copy one theme and make similar for other websites. In configuration, you can set theme per website.

You can create one main theme for one website. And for other website you can keep that main theme as parent theme. So you only need to override same CSS in other themes.

Comment: Thanks kishan, We don't want to like create separate them we need only css part only. changing theme according to website is a solution but only for css i wouldn't like to go with this solution. We could have more stored in future so its hard to create theme for all website.

Comment: But you can create one main theme. And for other website you can keep that main theme as parent theme. So you only need to override same CSS in other themes.

Comment: I updated my answer too for the same.

Comment: Thanks kishan, can you please help me how to do that in short way?

Comment: There are many tutorials on the internet.  You can refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108699/6084