# How to add and use a custom font in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, google-api, fonts

I purchased a magento 2 theme, but the theme uses the Google api font.

How can I use a custom local font?

Magento ver. 2.3.0

Comment: first create a child theme of purchased theme by using: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-magento-2

Add custom CSS to child theme by using https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108685/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-magento-2

After that you can add custom fonts to your theme!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. mkdir -p path_to_magento_install_dir/app/design/frontend/theme/custom-theme/web/fonts/CustomFont
2. upload myfonts_regular.ttf
3. mkdir -p path_to_magento_install_dir/app/design/frontend/theme/custom-theme/web/css
4. create fonts.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFonts';
    src: url('../fonts/CustomFont/myfonts_regular.ttf');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal
}
```

5. path_to_magento_install_dir/app/design/frontend/theme/custom-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
    <head>
        ...
        <css src="css/fonts.css" />
        ...
    </head>
```

Comment: Hi Alexander Bobylev,

Thanks for your advice.

I can't find default_head_blocks.xml, Only default.xml.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: e.g. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: Please check here  http://prntscr.com/mj6y59    app/design/frontend/Demo/demotheme/Magento_Theme/layout    this is my layout folder

Comment: create default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/fonts.css" />
    </head>
</page>

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css

Comment: Hi Alexander Bobylev, I refreshed the site cache and the source code of the page can see font.css  But I can still see https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Questrial:900,400%7CSource+Sans+Pro:400&subset=latin             
Please check here https://prnt.sc/mj79s0                                                                      How to remove googleapis.

Comment: Angelo, see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove

Comment: Although I still haven't deleted googleapis, I am very grateful for your help. 
http://prntscr.com/mj7rpp