# <depends/> node real purpose

Tags: magento2, module, dependency

In [How to disable Magento 2 reviews](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87781/how-to-disable-magento-2-reviews/) , we tried to disable the module *Magento_Review* through the `module:disable command`

But if you do that, in 2.1, you will have multiples errors of dependency.

```
./magento module:disable Magento_Review

Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_Review because modules depend on it:
Magento_Store: Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_AdminNotification: Magento_AdminNotification->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_Eav: Magento_Eav->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_Directory: Magento_Directory->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_Theme: Magento_Theme->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_Customer: Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_Indexer: Magento_Indexer->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_Cms: Magento_Cms->Magento_Theme->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_CatalogImportExport: Magento_CatalogImportExport->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Iazel_RegenProductUrl: Iazel_RegenProductUrl->Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite->Magento_CatalogImportExport->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
Magento_Backend: Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Review
```

For *Magento_Customer*, there is no `<Magento_Review/>` in the `<depends/>` node of `module.xml` . But i think it is because there are some blocks in *Mage_Customer* that extends *Mage_Reviews*

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab;

class Reviews extends \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid
```

So... the circular check is doing the job all alone.

**So my question : is the `<depends/>` node that important ? Or is it just "informational" ?**

Note: i know it is supposed to impact the load order. But the fact is that even if you put a module in `<depends>`, if yours is alphabetically before it, it will load BEFORE it. The `<sequence>` node does a better job for that. The proof of that is to rewrite a `di.xml`, yours will be read BEFORE the one in `<depends/>` . Try my solution in [How to disable Magento 2 reviews](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87781/how-to-disable-magento-2-reviews/) and replace the `<sequence/>` by `<depends/>` : it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<depends/>` node does not exist/supports in Magento 2 `module.xml` files(looks like it present only in early version of Magento). Module dependencies declared in composer.json, not in module.xml.

If you review composer.json from Customer module you will see dependency on Review module. It's why you cannot disable this module

Comment: Ah yes, obviously, thx. But i still don't understand the true impact of `<depends/>`. `<sequence/>` trully change the order of load, not `<depends/>`, or maybe in a way that does not follow my way of thinking :) (loading order of xml are very important when you rewrite things, and `<depends/>` do not change that... )

Comment: I update answer to be more clear about  `depends` nodes

Comment: Ok, so now i wonder where on earth i read that it worked in 2.x too. Maybe too much 1.x in brain :)