# Magento 2.3.0 disable module output not working

Tags: magento2

I tried to disable the module output for reviews (by changing my configuration), I now have the following (removed other configuration settings):

```
'websites' => [
    'base' => [
        'advanced' => [
            'modules_disable_output' => [
                'Magento_Review' => '1',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Which according to the docs should disable the reviews but when looking at the product page the reviews tab is still active?
I tried flushing all caches, executed bin/magento setup:di:compile but obviously I am doing something wrong but I can't seem to find out what I'm missing here.

Comment: Are you trying to remove review functionality?

Answer (score 0):

[From the doc I see this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html):

```
'system' =>
  array (
    'websites' =>
    array (
      'base' =>
      array (
        'advanced' =>
        array (
          'modules_disable_output' =>
          array (
            'Magento_Review' => '1',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

I see that you haven't included `system => array(` part. Check if that's the case.

Alternative way:

I would remove the functionality from the theme.
Just create a child theme (if you don't have one already) check below link:

[How to create a Child Theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-magento-2), and then inside your child theme create:

`app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

and add this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!--referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" /-->
        <referenceBlock name="product.review.form" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

[Ref](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87781/how-to-disable-magento-2-reviews#answer-162370)

Comment: Regardless if this works, disable output should work too.